# Obj-C: Autolayout IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker

Tags: objective-c, crash, autolayout, xib, crash-reports

After I push viewController,it uses xib and autolayout,It crash when it appear.It crash with the error log below:

> auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id:
>   4168} + <251:1>*0x1884aea0:IB auto generated at build time for view
>   with fixed frame.marker{id: 4170} + <251:1>*0x1884af30:IB auto
>   generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 4176} +
>   <251:1>*0x1884af60:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed
>   frame.marker{id: 4178} + <251:1>*0x1884aff0:IB auto generated at build
>   time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 4184} +
>   <251:1>*0x1884b020:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed
>   frame.marker{id: 4218} + <251:1>*0x1884b0b0:IB auto generated at build
>   time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 4224} +
>   <251:1>*0x1884b0e0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed
>   frame.marker{id: 4226} + <251:1>*0x1884b220:IB auto generated at build
>   time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 4186} +
>   <251:1>*0x1884b2b0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed
>   frame.marker{id: 4192} + <251:1>*0x1884b2e0:IB auto generated at build
>   time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 4194} +
>   <251:1>*0x1884b370:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed
>   frame.marker{id: 4200} + <251:1>*0x1884b3a0:IB auto generated at build
>   time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 4202} +
>   <251:1>*0x1884b430:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed
>   frame.marker{id: 4208} + <251:1>*0x1884b460:IB auto generated at build
>   time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 4210} +
>   <251:1>*0x1884b4f0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed

**I find the only crash in iOS 7 devices,while normal in iOS 8 ,there is a similar issue [XCode 6 project crashing after segue on ios 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941203/xcode-6-project-crashing-after-segue-on-ios-7-1) ,but it cannot solve my question**

can you please tell me why this could be happening?I donnot know which of my constraint wrong,I runs it several times and gets in the way when trying to read output. Thank you in advance =)

Comment: it the error log I did not use it anywhere

Comment: try posting image of your storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Okay, looks like you should add viewDidAppear for this. Moving the code to viewDidAppear may worked perfectly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you explain more detail,I just add a contentView as subview to my scrollView in viewDidLoad   and the code is                                  CGFloat proportion = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/320;
    CGFloat realContentH = 875 + (proportion - 1.0)*107;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.showView];
    [self.showView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make){
        make.edges.mas_equalTo(self.contentView);
        make.width.mas_equalTo(self.contentView);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(realContentH);
    }];